# Overflow is hidden, but there is a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, scrollbar

I've made a Image Slideshow with HTML5 + CSS. There is one div with `overflow:hidden`. The pictures are moved from the right side to the left and get visible in the div. In Chrome it's working fine, but in Firefox and IE there is a horizontal scrolling bar. How I could fix that?

Comment: Without no code, no way to help you.

Comment: As @drip said, on Stack Overflow we typically need code examples, especially attempts tried by the asker to solve the question thus far to help you.  Please provide sufficient code to let us diagnose what is going on.  (Try to not include a long list of irrelevant code though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at my blog's home page you see horizontally scrolling content, assuming you are above 600 pixels wide. http://love2dev.com. here are the CSS classes applied to the content wrapper to make things scroll horizontally.

```
.home-article-list-wrapper, .x-scroller-wrapper {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: auto;
```

}

```
.home-article-list-wrapper, .x-scroller-wrapper, .y-scroller-wrapper {
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
overflow-style: none;
-ms-scroll-chaining: none;
-ms-scroll-snap-type: proximity;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

}

The first rule overrides the second rule.